# Azure SQL Database :: SHRINKDATABASE increase the unallocated space

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, shrink

I'm trying to squeeze as much Azure SQL Databases as possible in order to make them fir inside a SQL Elastic Pool.

I'm using this query that allows me to compare the unallocated space before and after the operation:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1
GO

DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @dbName = DB_NAME()
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(@dbName, TRUNCATEONLY) 
GO

EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1
GO
```

I noticed that sometimes the unallocated space is actually increasing instead of decreasing:

[image]

This happened more than once. I read online that after the use of `SHRINKDATABASE` the indexes might be all over the place but here it seems that the `index_size` hasn't really changed. And the `unused` that is next to it it's just 50MB so that cannot be the problem:

[image]

How is this possible?

And how to properly `SHRINKDATABASE` on Azure SQL Database?

[You shouldn't shrink databases](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/) is not a valid reply because in this scenario, yes, I have to gain space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point ot reinvent the wheel. Microsoft propose an out-of-the-box solution for Azure SQL Database: [Auto-shrink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage?view=azuresql#auto-shrink)

```
-- Enable auto-shrink for the current database.
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET AUTO_SHRINK ON;
```

[image]

This made the trick.

If you then want to rebuild the indexes, once again, there is no point to reinvent the wheel. Microsoft propose [Rebuilding SQL Database indexes using Azure Automation](https://geeks.ms/davidjrh/2015/10/08/rebuilding-sql-database-indexes-using-azure-automation/)